# Matching paths in rails 3 using form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path

I am trying to follow the tutorial of making a twitter clone in ruby on rails (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXr1jAsBlPI&feature=relmfu). Unfortunately for me he is doing it in Rails 2.x.x and I am having some trouble keeping up. I am currently 41:34 when he is defining the paths in `routes.rb`.

I am getting this problem when I enter my 'show' page:

> "Routing Error No route matches {:action=>"show",
>   :controller=>"toggle_follow"} Try running rake routes for more
>   information on available routes."

This is what I have in the relevant files:

## routes.rb

```
match '/:username', :controller => 'home', :action => 'show'
match '/:username/toggle_follow', :controller => 'home', :action => 'toggle_follow'
```

## show.html.rb

```
<% if current_user.is_friend? @user %>
    <%= submit_tag "Following", :class => "button" %>
<% else %>
    <%= submit_tag "Stop following", :class => "button" %>
<% end %>
```

## home_controller.rb

```
def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    @flits = @user.all_flits

end

def toggle_follow
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    if current_user.is_friend? @user
        flash[:notice] = "You are no longer following @#{@user.username}"
        current_user.remove_friend(@user)
    else 
        current_user.add_friend(@user)
        flash[:notice] = "You are following @#{@user.username}"
    end

   redirect_to user_flits_path(@user.username)

end
```

...

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you've pasted... can you please show your `form_tag` ?

Comment: Oops sorry. I cut the #show.rb a little bit short...

Comment: Sorry i cut the show page a little bit short...
#show.rb
<%= form_tag toggle_follow_path do %>
    
    <% if current_user.is_friend? @user %>
        <%= submit_tag "Following", :class => "button" %>
    <% else %>
        <%= submit_tag "Stop following", :class => "button" %>
    <% end %>

<%- end -%>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved it...

in routes you have to enter:

## routes.db

match '/:username', :to => 'home#show', :as => 'user_flits'
match '/:username/toggle_follow', :to => 'home#toggle_follow', :as => 'toggle_follow'